# Variable undefined nodeJS MySQL query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a table with different post categories and I want to get the categories ID from the name. Example name: random => id: 1.

I got the variable like this:

```
const { name, title, cat, con, user_file } = req.body;
console.log(cat); //returnes the name as it should
```

This is my query:

```
var sql = "SELECT id FROM cat WHERE cat_name = ?";
db.query(sql, cat, function(err, result) {
    if(!result){
        return next();
    }
    const cat_id = result[0];
});
```

If I than try to console.log the cat_id I get undefined. I have tried doing this in many different way but it comes out the same every time. If I just run

```
SELECT id FROM cat WHERE cat_name = random
```

in thee database manager it works like it should and returnes the ID.

Edit: The purpose is to get the id to insert a foreign key into another table.

Comment: *"If I than try to console.log the cat_id I get undefined."* - And where do you try to do that?  The code shown has no such attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with variables only being saved in the query level. It console.logged the right number inside the db.query and the wrong one out of the db.query. So the solution for now is to put it inside I guess.

My solution now looks like this:

```
  exports.post = (req, res, next) => {
  let { cat } = req.body;
  let cat_id = 0;

  db.query(
    "SELECT id FROM cat WHERE cat_name = ?",
    [cat],
    async function (err, results) {
      if (!err) cat_id = results[0].id;
      else console.log(err);

      db.query(
        "INSERT INTO posts SET ?",
        { cat_id: cat_id },
        (error, results) => {
          if (error) console.log(error);
          else res.status(200).redirect("/post");
        }
      );
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` is an empty array. This is (assuming you're using the [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package) because your function call is incorrect.

When passing arguments to your query, [as explained here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries), you need to pass **an array** of values, not just a single value. For example:

```js
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?', ['David'], function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

In your case, that means you're looking for cats where the name is the first character of `cat` (e.g. `cat[0]`).

Comment: Ty for the answer. I checked out the documentation and tried this solution but it still comes out empty even if it has cat[0] , [cat],  if I add ' ' around it...

Comment: `db.query('SELECT id FROM cat WHERE cat_name = ?', [cat], function (err, results) {
   if(err) {console.log('error');} 
            else {console.log('no error?');}
            console.log(results);
            console.log(results[0]);
            console.log(results[0].id);
 });` doesn't return anything at all

Comment: Then run the SQL query manually and see if it's even meant to return something. I don't know if mongoose lets you get the raw SQL query it uses (for debugging), check their documentation.